# Floor heating: is electrical heating better for me?

Tags: floorheating

We want to lay 40qm of floor heating.

It seems to me that electrical heating i.e. thermoelectric elements eadiating warmth is more efficient to install and maintain.

Than, say, thin water pipes.

But maybe I'm wrong? How to decide?

Comment: What climate / where in the world are you?

Comment: Without knowing  you and what your preferences are **we can not tell what is best for you**. Perhaps if you change your question to - what is the most cost effective energy efficient in-floor heating. In terms of energy costs, It is  expensive to heat with electricity as apposed to hydroponic in floor.

Comment: *"How to decide ?"* Do **much research** about options, costs of installation, cost of operation, energy efficiency,  arm yourself with as much knowledge as you can and then, ask detailed and comprehensive questions to Pros, neighbors, stack exchanges, Then take all of that info and choose what is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hydronic heating is much cheaper to run but more costly to install. 40 square meters is a pretty large space for electric. If it's going to be your only heat source and you live in a cool climate go hydronic.